# How do I return a range of cells in Google Sheets based on a condition, using Python?

Tags: python, gspread

Below is an example of what I have in a Google Sheet:

```
1   | ID | Fav Color | Fav Book |
2   | 01 |  color1   |  book2   |
3   | 02 |  color2   |  book2   |
4   | 03 |  color2   |  book1   |
...
100 | 99 |  color1   |  book2   |
```

Using gspread, is it possible to find & print the ID and favorite color of only the people that say book2 is their favorite book? (expected result: print rows 2, 3, and 100)

I've been looking through the gspread docs, and just can't think of anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the worksheet, and then load all data either as a:

- [list of lists](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-worksheet-as-a-list-of-lists) `worksheet.get_all_values()`
- or [list of dicts](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-worksheet-as-a-list-of-dictionaries) `worksheet.get_all_records()`.

You can filter the list down using a list comprehension, or you could just loop over the entire dataset while printing and skip the rows where the favorite book isn't what you are looking for.

This example uses `get_all_records()` followed by a list comprehension to filter the list, and then printing.  I did not go to the trouble of setting up a test spreadsheet for testing so if I made an obvious errors please feel free to edit.

```py
import gspread

# Load Spreadsheet and primary worksheet
gc = gspread.service.account()
sheet = gc.open('My Data')
worksheet = sheet.sheet1 

# Load as a list of dicts
list_of_dicts = worksheet.get_all_records()

# Strip people who don't like book2.
book2_lovers = [d for d in list_of_dicts if d.get("Fav Book") == "book2"]

# Print header
print(f"{'ID':-^8}    {'Fav Color':-^15}")
# Print data
for person in book2_lovers:
    print(f"{person.get('ID'):^8}    {person.get('Fav Color'):^15}")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! If I may ask, what do ^8 and ^15 mean?

Comment: In an f-string, the info after the : is for formatting, where you can put a fill character (default is a space), justification (`<` for left justication, `^` for center justication, or `>` for right justification, and the number is how many spaces to fill. So `f"{value:^8}"` means to take the value and center over a space of 8 characters, using spaces to fill. 
  Here I just used it to sort of make columns for your output.  For example, `f"{'ID':-^8}"` results in `---ID---`